# Does this version of Grönwall's lemma hold?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, integral-inequality

Here is the lemma with more general hypothesis :

> Let $f,g,y\in L_{\text{loc}}^1(\mathbb{R})$ non-negatives such that for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $\displaystyle y(t) \le f(t) + \left \vert \int_{t_0}^t y(s)g(s)\mathrm{d}s \right\vert$. Then for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $\displaystyle y(t)\le f(t) + \left \vert\int_{t_0}^t f(u)g(u)\exp\left(\int_{u}^t g(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau\right)\mathrm{d}u \right \vert$.

In my opinion, the assumptions on $f,g$ and $y$ are sufficient to make that statement valid.

Moreover would the proof be similar to the classical Grönwall's lemma ? I mean that for the classical version, we can consider $t_0<t$ and study the function $\displaystyle t \mapsto f(t) +  \int_{t_0}^t y(s)g(s)\mathrm{d}s$ which is $\mathcal{C}^1$ in that case.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you sure that there is y(s) in the exponential?? Because I am getting g(s)!! There is no way to get y in the exponential!

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos Indeed you are right, sorry for the typo !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give a proof for $t>t_{0}$. Define $y(t)g(t)=h(t)$ and without loss of generality we assume that $g(t)>0$ for all $t$. (Otherwise we can define $\tilde{g}(t)=g(t)+\epsilon$ and get the result by letting $\epsilon$ tend to zero).

For all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $\displaystyle \frac{h(t)}{g(t)}\le f(t)+\int_{t_{0}}^{t} h(s)\mathrm{d}s$. Then $\displaystyle h(t)\leq f(t)g(t)+g(t)\int_{t_{0}}^{t}h(s)\mathrm{d}s$.

Set $\displaystyle z(t) = \int_{t_{0}}^{t} h(s)\mathrm{d}s$. As $z$ is in particular absolutely continuous then for almost every $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $z'(t)-z(t)g(t)\leq f(t)g(t)$.

Multiplying by the integrating factor $\displaystyle\exp\left(-\int_{s}^{t}g(r)\mathrm{d}r\right)$ we get $\displaystyle (\exp\left(-\int_{s}^{t}g(r)\mathrm{d}r\right)z(t))'\leq f(t)g(t) \exp\left(-\int_{s}^{t}g(r)\right)\mathrm{d}r$.

Taking $t=v$ it gives : $\displaystyle(\exp\left(-\int_{s}^{v}g(r)\mathrm{d}r\right)z(v))'\leq f(v)g(v) \exp\left(-\int_{s}^{v}g(r)\mathrm{d}r\right)$.

Integrating from $t_{0}$ to $t$ we get :
$\displaystyle \exp\left(-\int_{s}^{t}g(r)\mathrm{d}r\right)z(t) \leq \int_{t_{0}}^{t}f(v)g(v)\exp\left(-\int_{s}^{v}g(r)\mathrm{d}r\right)\mathrm{d}v$.

Multiplying with the exponential we obtain for almost every $t \in \mathbb{R}$ :
$\displaystyle z(t)\leq \int_{t_{0}}^{t}f(v)g(v)\exp\left(\int_{s}^{t}g(r)\mathrm{d}r-\int_{s}^{v}g(r)\mathrm{d}r\right) \mathrm{d}v=\int_{t_{0}}^{t}f(v)g(v)\exp\left(\int_{v}^{t}g(r)dr\right)dv$.

However for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$, $z(t)\geq\,y(t)-f(t)$ hence the result is proved !

The case where $t<t_{0}$ is treated likewise !

Comment: I guess we have to be very careful with the hypothesis of local integrability for $z'$. We have to deal with the notion of "almost everywhere" ! Moreover it seems that your proof is similar to the classical one with the hypothesis of continuity

Comment: But you assume that the integral of$\,\, y(t)g(t)$ exists right from the start! $h(t)=y(t)g(t)!!$

Comment: The function $(exp(-\int_{s}^{v}g(r)dr)z(v))$ is absolutely continuous since the product of AC functions is AC on bounded closed sets. So we can apply the $\int_{a}^{b}F'(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$ without any problem!

Comment: I was thinking about $z'(t)= h(t)$ on $\mathbb{R}$. As $h$ is just in $L_{\text{loc}}^1(\mathbb{R})$ we just have the previous equality almost everywhere I guess.

Comment: An absolutely continuous function (the z) is differentiable almost everywhere, but  all we need (see previous comment) is that for the function$ F(v)=(exp-\int_{s}^{v}g(r)dr)z(v)$ which is clearly absolutely continuous we have $\int_{t_{0}}^{t}F'(v)dv=F(t)-F(t_{0})$ and $F(t_{0})=0$ so it is equal to $F(t)$. Trust me!

Comment: You are referencing to the theorem 2.2 of this file https://sites.ualberta.ca/~rjia/Math418/Notes/chap3.pdf for instance ? I never used the concept of absolute continuity until now. However I think that the proof works almost everywhere so maybe in the statement it should have been a "for almost every $t \in \mathbb{R}$"...

Comment: Exactly! Theorem 2.2 is all we need! The almost everywhere has to do with the DERIVATIVE! But if we integrate we get F(x) an AC function, so the final result (in the integral form as it is given) holds EVERYWHERE because F is AC.!! That means that my z function is AC, so the final inequality holds for ALL x !!

Comment: Dear Maman, when will you approve my proof and give an upvote?? I gave all necessary explanations! I spent more than one hour proving this and I think I deserve some credit!

Comment: Sure, I tried to re-write it but I still think that with this method, it should be "for almost every $t \in \mathbb{R}$" in the conclusion of the statement...

Comment: Many thanks Mrs. Maman!! (The almost everywhere vanishes when we integrate). We get a relation which holds everywhere. It is OK!